# List of employees who are not managers

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to pull list of employees who are not managers...

Have a look at below two queries post if you have a better query...

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT Empno, Ename, Job, Sal
FROM Emp
WHERE Empno NOT IN (SELECT NVL(MGR,0) FROM Emp)
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT Empno, Ename, Job, Sal
FROM Emp
WHERE Empno NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MGR FROM Emp WHERE MGR IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: They should both work and are fine.  I prefer `coalesce()` to `nvl()` because `coalesce()` is the ANSI standard and works across databases.

Answer (score 4):

This may run faster depending on what fields are indexed:

```
select x.empno, x.ename, x.job, x.sal
  from emp x
  left join emp y
    on x.empno = y.mgr
 where y.mgr is null
```

Uses an outer join with the same table and filters in on rows where the empno never appears as a value in the mgr column of the table.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from emp a
where not exists 
(select 1 from emp where manager_id =a.emp_id);
```

above sql will find all the employee who is not manager, and exists function having better performance than not in

Answer (score 1):

Using a oracle specific function:

```
select Empno, Ename, Job, Sal from Emp
where CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
start with MGR is null
connect by prior Empno = MGR;
```

For see an example in how to use it see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/858e0/3

But if there's no hierarchy of managers is easier:

```
SELECT Empno, Ename, Job, Sal FROM Emp WHERE MGR IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

check it below:

```
SELECT E.LAST_NAME,E.EMPLOYEE_ID FROM EMPLOYEES EWHERE EMPLOYEE_ID not in 
   (SELECT MANAGER_ID FROM EMPLOYEES where MANAGER_ID is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE id <> managerid
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution that cover all cases

```sql
select e.name
  from employees as e
  left join employees as m
    on e.id = m.managerId
 where m.managerId is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query it will work

```
SELECT Empno, Ename, Job, Sal
FROM Emp
WHERE Job != 'MANAGER'
```

of

```
SELECT Empno, Ename, Job, Sal
FROM Emp
WHERE Job NOT LIKE 'MANAGER'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table empinfo(last_name varchar2(20),job_title varchar2(20));
insert into empinfo (last_name,job_title)values('Peterson','Manager');
insert into empinfo (last_name,job_title)values('Pollard','Project Engineer');
insert into empinfo (last_name,job_title)values('Taylor','Developer');
insert into empinfo (last_name,job_title)values('Mlinga','Tester');
select last_name,job_title from empinfo where job_title NOT LIKE 'Manager';
```

Answer (score 0):

`select * from employee where emp_id not in (select manager_id from employee where manager_id IS NOT NULL);`

or

`select t1.* from from sales.staff t1
where not exists ( select 1 from sales.staff t2 where t1.staff_id=t2.manager_id )`

find more :
[Finding employees who are not managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54946639/finding-employees-who-are-not-managers/54946667)