# Finding employees who are not managers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where we have staff_id and manager_id. Attached screenshot.

I found managers by using this query:

```
select e.first_name as employee , m.first_name as manager
from sales.staffs E
inner JOIN sales.staffs M ON M.staff_id = E.manager_id
```

How do I pull a list of employees who are not managers?

My sample table

[image: My sample table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use not exists

```
select t1.* from from sales.staff t1
         where not exists ( select 1 from sales.staff t2 where t1.staff_id=t2.manager_id )
```

if you use `not in` then  do `null`  chechk

```
select t.* from sales.staff  t 
where t.staff_id not in (select manager_id from sales.staff where manager_id IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using:

```
select * from sales.staff 
where staff_id not in (select manager_id from sales.staff)
```

Comment: I tried the query you mentioned.  It returns no rows.  But if I try 
SELECT * FROM sales.staffs A
WHERE A.staff_id not in (SELECT DISTINCT sales.staffs.manager_id FROM sales.staffs WHERE sales.staffs.manager_id IS NOT NULL)
It works. I am trying to figure out why?

Comment: According to your data it should show: 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, and 10, since these values do not show up in the `manager_id` column.

Answer (score 0):

I guess all the ids of managers are stored in the column `manager_id`. 
Also if the column `manager_id` is `null` then this employee is also a manager(?).
So to get all the managers you should do:

```
select * from sales.staffs 
where 
  manager_id is null
  or
  staff_id in (select distinct manager_id from sales.staffs)
```

Now to get the employees that are not managers you just negate the condition:

```
select * from sales.staffs 
where 
  manager_id is not null
  and
  staff_id not in (select distinct manager_id from sales.staffs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response . Appreciate it.   For employees that are not managers I had to change it little bit to get results as the .  select * from sales.staffs 
where 
  manager_id is not null
  and
  staff_id not in (select distinct manager_id from sales.staffs WHERE sales.staffs.manager_id IS NOT NULL)

Comment: @mgr810 distinct rejects any null so you don't need ` WHERE sales.staffs.manager_id IS NOT NULL`, as the code above

Answer (score -1):

As an extension on @The Impalers correct answer, your query would become:

```
select e.first_name as employee , m.first_name as manager
from sales.staffs E
inner JOIN sales.staffs M ON M.staff_id = E.manager_id
WHERE m.manager_id IS NULL
```

Since you want to have a list of people who are not managers you could go for this solution, which will check if the manager_id is equal to NULL (assuming this means no manager).

A different solution would be to LEFT JOIN based on NOT EXIST, this would filter your table and would significantly lower your fetch time.

Comment: You won't get a `NULL` value on an `INNER JOIN`, use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Woops! You are correct, changed my text :)

Comment: Thanks for your response both of you. Appreciate it.